# How to iterate over the result of an array in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[image: DOM]

Hello, I am trying to iterate over an array to get to the class of `tag.highlight` within the span which only gets activated after iterating 30 times over the `span.tag`.
I am trying to get to the highlighted tag in order to connect to an API. However, I am getting stuck with the below code where I am unable to select the highlight tag in order to select the text inside that tag. When I inspect my page in the browser it shows:

```
(2) [span.tag, span.tag]
```

when I expand the above, it displays:

```
0: span.tag
1: span.tag.highlight
length: 2
```

I want to iterate over 1: `span.tag.highlight` in order to get to the `innerText`. After expanding the above again, I want to get to the below-shown example of `className`.

`console.log(form)` gives me the node of `className`
but I do not know how I iterate from here to get to `className.value === 'highlight'`.

```
childNodes: NodeList [text]
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList(2) ['tag', 'highlight', value: 'tag highlight']
className: "tag highlight"
clientHeight: 45
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 72
contentEditable: "inherit"
```

I have tried using `document.getElementsByClassName('highlight'))` and I do not understand why the highlight tag is an empty array when there should be one element highlighted in it.

Can you please help me understand and solve the below code? Thanks in advance.
eg. I tried the below:

```js
const form = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tag'));

console.log(form);
// gives me the array of childNodes,...className that contains className 'highlight'

form.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element); // only gives a span tag with no highlight mentioned.
});
//for event change I am using onChange when the tag is highlighted. Not sure if this would be the correct event to be selected.

if (highlightTag(randomTag)) {
  form.addEventListener('onChange', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="tags" style="">
  <span class="tag highlight">xyz</span>
  <span class="tag">abc</span>
</div>
```

Comment: change `onChange` to `change` in your event listener.

Comment: both `form.forEach()` and `document.getElementsByClassName('highlight')` seem to work  https://jsfiddle.net/4znepjw9/

Comment: it should work but when I console.log it displays an empty array when it should display the existing length.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're looking for but I can isolate "highlight" simply enough.

But I did find this on the MDN page for `document.getElementsByClassName()`:

> Warning: This is a live `HTMLCollection`. Changes in the DOM will
> reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by
> this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically
> be removed. Be aware of this for iteration purposes.

Not sure if it applies, but you should be aware

This snippet offers several ways to isolate class `highlight` and get its innerText

```js
console.log("From Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tag')");
const form = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tag'));
form.forEach((element) => {
  console.log(element);
});

console.log(`${form[0].classList[1]}, ${form[0].innerText}`);
console.log("");

console.log("From document.getElementsByClassName('highlight')");
const f2 = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
for (const e of f2) {
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(`${f2[0].classList[1]}, ${f2[0].innerText}`);
console.log("");

console.log("From document.getElementsByClassName('tag')");
const x = document.getElementsByClassName('tag')
for (const e of x) {
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(`${x[0].classList[1]}, ${x[0].innerText}`);
console.log("");

console.log('From document.querySelectorAll(".tag.highlight")');
const q = document.querySelectorAll(".tag.highlight");
console.log(`${q[0].classList[1]}, ${q[0].innerText}`);
```

```html
<div id="tags" style="">
  <span class="tag highlight">xyz</span>
  <span class="tag">abc</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, I'm trying to iterate to get the class "highlight", I realized that I wasn't getting the class highlight cause I had to use the async await function.

Comment: Ahh...timing is everything :) Happy Coding.